# PERMANOVA with vegan (adonis) for three factors and repeated measures?

Tags: vegan, permanova

I have three factors (Status, Time.Point, Treatment) each with 2 levels. Time.Point factor is "before" and "after" (the repeated measures). The data is unbalanced though (e.g. some before sample with no matching after)

I want to know if there are main effects of any of the three factors and if there are any interactions between Status:Treatment, Status:Time.Point, and Status:Treatment:Time.Point.

Here is what I have so far:

```r
perm_design <- how(nperm = 999, blocks = sampledf$Time.Point)
adonisresult <- adonis2(formula = distance_calc ~ Status + 
    Time.Point + Treatment, data = sampledf, 
    method = "bray", permutations = perm_design,
    by= "margin")
```

Questions:

1. would the block in `perm_design` be Sample.ID or should it be Time.Point as I am blocking around Time.Point? EDIT: nevermind- it should be Time.Point and i have edited this in the code.
2. I have set `by=margin` because I don't want the order to matter but obviously when I include an interaction term it just computes that. So to get around this, do I run this again and again for each interaction term (i.e. just for Status:Treatment, Status:Time.Point, and Status:Treatment:Time.Point)? Is that a valid approach? I absolutely want to avoid fishing for results but I don't know how else to do this.

Answer (score 0):

I am by no means an expert, but these are exactly something I struggled with also, so here is my stab at it:

1. I would recommend the following for permutation design.

```
how(within = Within(type = "series"),
    plots = Plots(strata = Sample.ID),
    nperm = 999)
```

As far as I know, `Within` specifies how to deal with having two values for each `Sample.ID` would be dealt with. `plots` specifies that each `Sample.ID` is the subject of repeated measure.
`Blocks` actually doesn't work. If you need to use it (i.e. if I am misunderstanding and you must use `Sample.ID` as block), you can pass it within `how()` as `blocks = Sample.ID`. See Gavin (author of `"permute"`)'s answer to my question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78209284/adonis2-blocking-error-while-doing-repeated-measures-via-how/78210421#78210421).

2. ahhh... marginal tests with multiple interactions. Afaict, there is no way of doing it and I have been doing what you are describing. As [the author of `vegan` writes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77199153/adonis2-marginal-tests-for-models-with-main-effects-and-interaction-terms), there is no way to test interactions and main effects at the same time ("no one has written those"). [This archived email thread](https://stat.ethz.ch/pipermail/r-sig-ecology/2018-October/005822.html) also comes to the same conclusion.
   Now, for the workaround, I have also been doing the "old school ANOVA" approach. I test `A*B*C`, which gives me `A:B:C`, if that is significant I switch gears to pairwise comparisons. If not significant, formula is adjusted to `A*B*C-A:B:C`, which gives me `A:B`, `B:C`, `A:C`. If none of these are significant, then I test for `A+B+C.` If any of the interactions are significant, I use pairwise comparisons.
   So far no one I know (including my institution's statistical department) has any better idea, and I think even if it may not be 100% elegant, it is a defensible approach. If someone else (or you, now that you had to wait a bit), have better ideas, I would love to know.

Hope that helps.